# $h(x,y)=f(x)-f(y)$ is integrable iff $f$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have problems trying to prove one implication of the following **proposition**

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function and let $h: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined as $h(x,y)=f(x)-f(y)$. Show that $h$ is integrable iff $f$ is integrable.

I could prove that $h$ integrable implies $f$ integrable:

Suppose $h$ is integrable, by Fubini-Tonelli we have $$\infty >\int_{[0,1]^2}|h|=\int_{[0,1]}(\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-f(y)|dy)dx$$

This means $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-f(y)|dy < \infty$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$, Pick $x_0$ for which the inequality is satisfied. Then $$\int_{[0,1]}|f(y)|dy \leq \int_{[0,1]}|f(y)-f(x_0)|dy+\int_{[0,1]}|f(x_0)|dx < \infty$$

From the chain of inequalities above it follows that $f$ is integrable.

I got stuck trying to show $f$ integrable $\implies$ $h$ is integrable

Again we have the equality $$\int_{[0,1]^2}|h|=\int_{[0,1]}(\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-f(y)|dy)dx,$$ and for each $x$, it is clear that $g(x)=\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-f(y)|dy< \infty$. I would like to show that $\int_{[0,1]}g(x)dx< \infty$, how could I show this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is only true if $f(x_0) < \infty$ though. By assuming that it's true (for nearly all $x_0$...) You basically assumed what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Given $h$ is integrable, why does $\int |f(y) - f(x)| dx$ measurable in $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|h(x,y)| \le |f(x)| + |f(y)|$.

$\int |h(x,y)| dx  \le \int |f(x)| dx + |f(y)|$.

$\int \int |h(x,y)| dx dy  \le \int |f(x)| dx + \int |f(y)|dy$.